# Setting up a result backend (rpc) with Celery in Django

Tags: python, django, celery

I am attempting to get a result backend working on my local machine for a project I'm working on but I am running into an issue.

Currently I am trying to create a queue system in order for my lab to create cases. This is to prevent duplicate sequence numbers from being used. I am already using Celery for our printing so I figured I would create a new Celery queue and use that to handle the case. The front-end also needs to get the results of the case creations to display the case number that was created.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#rabbitmq

I was following the above tutorial on getting my Celery configured. Below is the source:

celeryconfig.py:

```
from kombu import Queue
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'celery'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = 'celery'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = 'direct'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc://'
CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT = False

CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('celery',    routing_key="celery"),
    Queue('case_creation',       routing_key='create.#')
)

CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'case.tasks.create_case': {
        'queue': 'case_creation',
        'routing_key': 'create.1'
    },
    'print.tasks.connect_and_serve': {
        'queue': 'celery',
        'routing_key': 'celery'
    }
}
```

celery.py:

```
import os

from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings.local')

app = Celery('proj', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

app.config_from_object('proj.celeryconfig')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

tasks.py:

```
import celery
from django.db import IntegrityError

from case.case_create import CaseCreate


@celery.task(bind=True)
def create_case(self, data, user, ip):
    try:
        acc = CaseCreate(data, user, ip)
        return acc.begin()
    except IntegrityError as e:
        self.retry(exc=e, countdown=2)
```

Here is my view that calls the above task:

```
@require_authentication()
@requires_api_signature()
@csrf_exempt
@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def api_create_case(request):
    result = create_case.delay(json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8')), request.user, get_ip_address(request))
    print(str(result))  # Prints the Task ID
    print(str(result.get(timeout=1)))  # Throws error
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'result': str(result)}), status=200)
```

I start my celery queue with the following command:

```
celery -A proj worker -Q case_creation -n case_worker -c 1
```

When I run the celery worker I do see results show up under config:

```
 -------------- celery@case_worker v3.1.16 (Cipater)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Windows-8-6.2.9200
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         proj:0x32a2990
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     rpc://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> case_creation    exchange=celery(direct) key=create.#
```

When I run the program and submit a new case this is the error message that I get:

```
No result backend configured.  Please see the documentation for more information.
```

I have attempted every single thing I can find online. Is there anyone out there that can point me in the right direction? I'm so very close and so very tired of looking at this code.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to keep your result, try this [Keeping Results](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#keeping-results)

```
app = Celery('proj', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
```

#### EDIT

> Make sure the client is configured with the right backend.
>
> If for some reason the client is configured to use a different backend than the worker, you will not be able to receive the result, so make sure the backend is correct by inspecting it:

Try this to see the output:

```
>>> result = task.delay(…)
>>> print(result.backend)
```

other solutions will be instead of

```
app = Celery('proj',
         backend='amqp',
         broker='amqp://',
         include=['proj.tasks'])
```

Try:

```
app = Celery('proj',
             broker='amqp://',
             include=['proj.tasks'])
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='amqp'
)
```

Comment: I tried amqp and I get the same error message that says "No result backend configured." When I start celery I see that the results config is updated to amqp, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Note that amqp result backend has been removed since the version 5.0